# Httpservice mysterious url change between flex 3 and flex 4 version

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3

I have an application migrated from flex 3 to Flex 4.
I haven't changed anything in the functionality of the code. I call struts actions using a HTTPService:

```
var service:HTTPService = new HTTPService();
service.url=  "someAction.do"
service.send(params);
```

The problem is that when I'm using the flex 3 swf generated by flash builder 3, there is no problem, the action is sent like I want it to, to the url /someUrl

```
localhost:8080/someurl/someAction.do
```

If I use flex 4 swf in the same situation, in the same war archive. **The only thing I change is the swf** , the url will also contain the path of the swf which causes a problem

```
localhost:8080/someurl/path/to/swf/someAction.do
```

Anyone knows what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for the rootURL property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html#rootURL) suggests that this is intended behavior for Flex 4:

> ..., the relative URL is computed automatically based on the location of the SWF running this application.  ...

A possible solution would be to use the `rootURL` property, though that requires also using the Flex server proxy which might introduce other problems.

Comment: I tried printing rootURL for both flex 3 and Flex 4 and it's the same